# Tag name in CSS selector (e.g. div#id): how is it read? (Left to right or right to left?)

Tags: performance, css, css-selectors

So I came across a couple of articles on CSS optimization:

- http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Apparently CSS is read from right to left. That means that `div table a` is read like: first all `a` elements on the page are retrieved, then all `table` elements that have an a in them (right?), then all `div` elements with both of those in them (right?).

My question, which I couldn't find an answer to anywhere, is: how is a CSS rule like `div#div_id` parsed? Do first all elements with the id "div_id" get parsed, and is a filter then applied to fetch from that bunch of #div_id elements all `div` elements? Or are first all `div` elements parsed, and is a filter then applied to fetch everything with the id "div_id"?

The first article I mentioned says that the recommended order of efficiency in CSS is: #id > > .class > tag > rest. But what about `tag#id`?

**To clarify:** I like to type `div#div_id` just to have it clear for myself that #div_id applies to a `div` element without having to look up the HTML to find out which element's styling I'm looking at, but I wouldn't want to use it that way if it costs me much of my website's performance .What would be the recommended way of writing the rule then? Should I drop the tags in my selectors? Is it really that expensive?

### The answer

The answer would be, as jbutler483 says: leaving the tag name out is faster. If you want to have clarification on what element you're styling, don't use `div#my_id` but `#div_my_id`. If you don't care that much about performance, you could still go with the `div#my_id`, but it will be a bit slower (but you can ask yourself if it will really impact your application that much).

Comment: What is the point of `tag#id`? Do you have elements on multiple pages which have the same id and a different tag? id is required to be unique, so you could never have two elements on the same page with the same id and different tags.

Comment: Well, yes, sometimes I do. Let's say I have a p.bold and a span.bold, and I want them to behave differently. (Ok, that's not the ID, but the question remains the same.)

Comment: I know that makes sense with classes. I was specifically asking why you are doing it with IDs, which are required to be unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think you've gotten a little confused.

In your example, you use:

```
div table a
```

So i'll use that.

Pretty much, that could look like this in your html

```
<div>
 <table>
    <a>
      //styling applied here
    </a>
 </table>
</div>
```

or something else like

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <table>  
     <tr>
       <th>hi there</th>
       <th>
          <a>i'm an a tag!</a>
```

So, looking at that:

```
div table a
```

will be

```
div table a

 ^    ^   ^
 |    |   |
 |    |    a child
 |    |
 |   parent
 |
grandparent
```

This means that you'll be styling any 'a' element that is a child/descendant of a table, which, in turn, is a descendant of a div element

so, in your other example:

```
div#div_id
```

you would be styling all id's of div_id in which have a div as a parent.

---

BTW looking at your example, I would like to point out that (in case you didn't know):

- the id attribute should be unique
- an `<a>` attribute shouldn't be used directly within a `<table>` element (instead nest it within a th or td tag)
- If you wish to style multiple elements (of varying types), it would be more efficient to create a class, and use that instead

---

## Answer after Clarification:

---

Your

```
 div#div_id
```

In HTML, since the id is *meant* to be unique, it will look up 'all id's' with the specified id.

It will **then** check if it is a div element.

This seems to be a bad example, as obviously some (older) browsers will only look for the first id, and return it instead of checking the whole webpage for any 'duplicate' id's.

With your id's being unique, you could then drop your **tag** as it will be left redundant/ no use

---

## Summary

---

So, an example of this extended conversation in the comments:

if I wanted to style a single div (and still know it *was* a div that i was adding styling to), i would use the naming convention of:

```
<div id="my-div-to-style">
             ^
             |
```

[the word 'div' here could be anything]

in my **css** i would write:

```
       _  this word must match the
      /   id i used above
     |
#my-div-to-style{
//styling...
}
```

If i wanted to add the same styling to multiple div elements (with the scope to add it to others), i would instead use a **class**:

```
<div class="myDivStyle">
```

and then use:

```
.myDivStyle{
 //styling...
}
```

in this last example, I would not be restricted to just styling divs, so i wouldn't include this in my naming:

```
<div class="myStyle">
<a class="myStyle">
<table class="myStyle">



.myStyle{
//styling for any element I want
}
```

Comment: `div table a` can refer to any `<a>` inside the table, you're confusing it with `div table > a`

Comment: I will clarify my post, but I was *pointing out* in case the OP didn't know

Comment: I think the questions author knows what they are selecting, their question is rather how does the browser look up the element being selected by CSS, does it select all `a` tags and check up the dom tree or does it go from the `div` tag and check downwards?

Comment: I did know that, but thanks nevertheless :).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that clarifies things. So say I now use the "div" in "div#id" for clarification that #id applies to a div, what would you recommend to still be able to recognize that #id applies to a div, without prepending the "div" tag to it? Would you rather use "#div-id" or something like that, or do you think "div#id" is acceptable for readability, as long as you make sure ID's are kept unique?

Comment: "It will then check if it is contained within a div." using your example it will check if it IS a div. Not CONTAINED in a div

Comment: I would purely say `#IDHere`, knowing it would only be applied to a single element (since i only use unique ids)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: sorry, typo! corrected ty

Comment: So if I'd want to recognize that #IDHere applies to a div, should I, for example, call it #div-my-id instead of div#my-id?

Comment: yes, I will explicitly explain with a sample (as all these 'divs' and 'ids' are frying my brain, let alone yours no doubt!)

Comment: "`div#div_id`you would be styling all id's of div_id in which have a div as a parent." - There is no space, so you will be styling divs with #div_id. They're not necessarily a child of a div.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, rules are parsed right to left, the same applies here.

Although duplicate `id` values are **not valid**, it is up to the browser to decide whether to accept and parse them, the below (in Chrome) for example, renders the first and last elements with red text.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/mjvkbm77/)

```css
div#test {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>text</div>
<span id='test'>
    text
</span>
<div id='test'>text</div>
```

In modern browsers you may want to be less mindful of selector resolution performance and instead look to obtain valid CSS adhering to best practices, keeping selectors as short and concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What about `tag#id`? The [second link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) you mention contains the answer.

> Don’t qualify ID rules with tag names or classes
>
> If a rule has an ID selector as its key selector, don’t add the tag
>   name to the rule. Since IDs are unique, adding a tag name would slow
>   down the matching process needlessly.
>
> Don’t qualify class rules with tag names
>
> The previous concept also applies here.  Though classes can be used
>   many times on the same page, they are still more unique than a tag.

Comment: I like to type div#div_id just to have it clear for myself that #div_id applies to a div element without having to look up the HTML to find out which element's styling I'm looking at, but I wouldn't want to use it that way if it costs me much of my website's performance. What would be the recommended way of writing the rule then? Should I drop the tags in my selectors? Is it really that expensive?

Comment: @minitauros The way CSS queries are written generally does not have a significant impact on performance, and browsers keep improving, so I would say that a clear, consistent coding style comes first.

Answer (score 0):

You may learn more about your question here: [css-tricks => efficiently rendering html](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)

> There are four kinds of key selectors: ID, class, tag, and universal. It is that same order in how efficient they are.

```
#main-navigation {   }      /* ID (Fastest) */
body.home #page-wrap {   }  /* ID */
.main-navigation {   }      /* Class */
ul li a.current {   }       /* Class *
ul {   }                    /* Tag */
ul li a {  }                /* Tag */
* {   }                     /* Universal (Slowest) */
#content [title='home']     /* Universal */
```

> When we combine this right-to-left idea, and the key selector idea, we can see that this selector isn't very efficient:

```
#main-nav > li {   }  /* Slower than it might seem */
```

> Even though that feels weirdly counter-intuitive... Since ID's are so efficient we would think the browser could just find that ID quickly and then find the li children quickly. But in reality, the relatively slow li tag selector is run first.